# Use Resources to set Button's ToolTips in a program

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a program that the user can switch the program language on run time.

I store the current language used in Program Settings and I access it in my program using

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Language
```

Now In my `xaml` View files I want my `buttons` to change their `ToolTips` when the user change the current language. 
I have two `Rescorces` files: `EnglishRescource.resx`and`FrenchRescource.rex` 
And I bind the `ToolTips` of my `buttons` using

```
ToolTip="{Binding Path=NewDocument, Source={StaticResource Resources}}"
```

But I don't know if this is a correct approach. How can I bind to the correct `Resource` file when the language is switched.

**EDIT**

I renamed my resources files to  `Resources.En-US.resx` and  `Resources.Fr-CA.resx`

Comment: What is `Resources` and `NewDocument`? Where do they reside? What those two resource files have to do with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you are naming them {language}Resource.resx instead of the standard, Resource.{locale}.resx?

A few sites that might be of use

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_Resx_Localization.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx